# how to display either of the two database values in a label using autocomplete in php

Tags: php, autocomplete, label

This is my following code :

```
<?php include("config.php");
include("session-user.php");

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that    autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT product_title, product_details, product_id  FROM tbl_product WHERE product_title LIKE '".$term."%' OR product_details LIKE '".$term."' and is_delete = '0'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))//loop through the retrieved values
{
    $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
    $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);
    $row['product_id']=htmlentities($row['product_id']);
    $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

currently it displays only one of the `labels`, I want to search with either of the two labels

How can I achieve it?

Comment: due to same indexes it over-write first one, use  like `$row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
    $row['label1']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);` check i have changed second one index to  `label1`

Comment: Now its not showing the label1 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in this code:-

```
 $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
 $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);
```

due to same indexes(`label`) it over-write first one, use like :-

```
 $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
 $row['label1']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);
```

check i have changed second one index to `label1`

**autocomplete work with one label per value so you can concatenate them (label-label1) and show.**

***Or***

may be this helps you:-

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))//loop through the retrieved values
{
    if($row['product_title'] !=='' && $row['product_details'] ==''){ // if product_title is present but  product_details is not present
      $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
      $row['product_id']=htmlentities($row['product_id']);
      $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
    }else if($row['product_details'] !=='' && $row['product_title'] ==''){ // if product_details is present but  product_title is not present
      $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);
      $row['product_id']=htmlentities($row['product_id']);
      $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
    }else if($row['product_details'] !=='' && $row['product_title'] !==''){ // if both are present
      $row['label']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
      $row['product_id']=htmlentities($row['product_id']);
      $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
    } 
}
```

Note:- in this above code if both values (`product_title` and `product_title`) are present then `product_title` will show as a label otherwise corresponding value will show as a label.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $row['label1']=htmlentities($row['product_title']);
    $row['label2']=htmlentities($row['product_details']);
```

and change query to

```
$qstring = "SELECT product_title, product_details, product_id  FROM tbl_product WHERE product_title LIKE '".$term."%' OR product_details LIKE '".$term."%' and is_delete = '0'";
```